# Prevent on input even from bubbling

Tags: javascript, input

I have 10 input fields. Where a user types something on the input field, I want to do the variable eventName in the dataLayer. If a user has already interacted with the input field, I want to prevent the the dataLayer push from bubbling.

What I've tried

```
    var formField = document.querySelectorAll('[data-interaction-text]'),
    dataLayer = dataLayer || [];



for (var i = 0; i < formField.length; i++) {
    formField[i].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        var eventName = 'input-field-' + e.target.getAttribute('data-interaction-text'),
            eventNamesAlreadyUsed = [];



        if (eventNamesAlreadyUsed.indexOf(eventName) === -1) {
            eventNamesAlreadyUsed.push(eventName);
            dataLayer.push({
                event: eventName
            });
           
        }

    });
}
```

Expected outcome:
A user interacts with input field. If they try again nothing happens.

Comment: There's no need for `dataLayer || []`. It returns an empty NodeList if nothing matches.

Comment: `eventNamesAlreadyUsed` is declared inside the function, so it doesn't persist between different events. Declare it outside the function instead.